# Starting Google Chrome with a registered proxy on i3

Tags: google-chrome, i3-wm

Good day!

Not so long ago, I switched to the i3 window manager (there is not enough performance on the old computer) and I have a problem with running Google Chrome with the option --proxy-pac-url.
I need to register this option in the console and run an application through it in order for the Internet to work. Although I can detach the application from the terminal, but I would like to just launch the browser with the desired setting via mod + d.

How to do it?